# Rails error 'unset' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create new rails application using kickoff_tailwind

Firstly I ran `rails new tweeter -m template.rb -j esbuild` and make rails application got output as

```
$  rails new tweeter -m template.rb -j esbuild
      create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  .gitattributes
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in F:/kickoff_tailwind-main/kickoff_tailwind-main/tweeter/.git/
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/storage.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_7_0.rb
      create  config/initializers/permissions_policy.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/master.key
      append  .gitignore
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/pids
      create  tmp/pids/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/system
      create  test/system/.keep
      create  test/application_system_test_case.rb
      create  storage
      create  storage/.keep
      create  tmp/storage
      create  tmp/storage/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_7_0.rb
       apply  F:/kickoff_tailwind-main/kickoff_tailwind-main/template.rb
     gemfile    devise (~> 4.8, >= 4.8.1)
     gemfile    friendly_id (~> 5.4, >= 5.4.2)
     gemfile    cssbundling-rails
     gemfile    name_of_person
     gemfile    sidekiq (~> 6.5, >= 6.5.4)
     gemfile    stripe
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies.........
Using rake 13.0.6
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.10
Using minitest 5.17.0
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.12.0
Using racc 1.6.2
Using crass 1.0.6
Using rack 2.2.5
Using nio4r 2.5.8
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using marcel 1.0.2
Using mini_mime 1.1.2
Using date 3.3.3
Using timeout 0.3.1
Using public_suffix 5.0.1
Using bcrypt 3.1.18
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using bundler 2.3.25
Using msgpack 1.6.0
Using matrix 0.4.2
Using regexp_parser 2.6.1
Fetching connection_pool 2.3.0
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using thor 1.2.1
Using zeitwerk 2.6.6
Using io-console 0.6.0
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using rexml 3.2.5
Fetching redis 4.8.0
Using rubyzip 2.3.2
Using websocket 1.2.9
Using sqlite3 1.5.4 (x64-mingw-ucrt)
Using i18n 1.12.0
Fetching stripe 8.0.0
Using tzinfo 2.0.5
Using websocket-driver 0.7.5
Using nokogiri 1.13.10 (x64-mingw-ucrt)
Using rack-test 2.0.2
Using warden 1.2.9
Using sprockets 4.2.0
Using puma 5.6.5
Using net-protocol 0.2.1
Using addressable 2.8.1
Using bootsnap 1.15.0
Using reline 0.3.2
Using tzinfo-data 1.2022.7
Using loofah 2.19.1
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using net-imap 0.3.4
Using net-pop 0.1.2
Using net-smtp 0.3.3
Using selenium-webdriver 4.7.1
Using capybara 3.38.0
Using activesupport 7.0.4
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.4.4
Using irb 1.6.2
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using globalid 1.0.0
Using activemodel 7.0.4
Using name_of_person 1.1.1
Using debug 1.7.1
Using actionview 7.0.4
Using activejob 7.0.4
Using mail 2.8.0
Using webdrivers 5.2.0
Using actionpack 7.0.4
Using jbuilder 2.11.5
Using actioncable 7.0.4
Using actionmailer 7.0.4
Using railties 7.0.4
Using sprockets-rails 3.4.2
Using responders 3.0.1
Using jsbundling-rails 1.1.1
Using stimulus-rails 1.2.1
Using turbo-rails 1.3.2
Fetching cssbundling-rails 1.1.2
Using activerecord 7.0.4
Using web-console 4.2.0
Using devise 4.8.1
Using activestorage 7.0.4
Fetching friendly_id 5.5.0
Using actionmailbox 7.0.4
Using actiontext 7.0.4
Using rails 7.0.4
Installing cssbundling-rails 1.1.2
Installing connection_pool 2.3.0
Installing friendly_id 5.5.0
Installing redis 4.8.0
Installing stripe 8.0.0
Fetching sidekiq 6.5.8
Installing sidekiq 6.5.8
Bundle complete! 21 Gemfile dependencies, 85 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
       rails  javascript:install:esbuild
Compile into app/assets/builds
      create  app/assets/builds
      create  app/assets/builds/.keep
      append  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      append  .gitignore
      append  .gitignore
Add JavaScript include tag in application layout
      insert  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
Create default entrypoint in app/javascript/application.js
      create  app/javascript
      create  app/javascript/application.js
Add default package.json
      create  package.json
Add default Procfile.dev
      create  Procfile.dev
Ensure foreman is installed
         run  gem install foreman from "."
Successfully installed foreman-0.87.2
Parsing documentation for foreman-0.87.2
Done installing documentation for foreman after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
Add bin/dev to start foreman
      create  bin/dev
Install esbuild
         run  yarn add esbuild from "."
yarn add v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 2 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
└─ esbuild@0.16.14
info All dependencies
├─ @esbuild/win32-x64@0.16.14
└─ esbuild@0.16.14
Done in 10.41s.
Add build script
         run  npm pkg set scripts.build="esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets" from "."
         run  yarn build from "."
yarn run v1.22.19
$ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
X [ERROR] Could not resolve "app/javascript/*.*"

  It looks like you are trying to use glob syntax (i.e. "*") with esbuild. This syntax is typically handled by your shell, and isn't handled by esbuild itself. You must expand glob syntax first before passing your paths to esbuild.

1 error
node:child_process:910
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: F:\kickoff_tailwind-main\kickoff_tailwind-main\tweeter\node_modules\@esbuild\win32-x64\esbuild.exe app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:871:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:907:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\kickoff_tailwind-main\kickoff_tailwind-main\tweeter\node_modules\esbuild\bin\esbuild:215:28)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 17592,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}


     ill be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of '.ruby-version', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'Gemfile', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'Gemfile.lock', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'Procfile.dev', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'README.md', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'Rakefile', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/assets/config/manifest.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/assets/stylesheets/actiontext.css', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/controllers/application_controller.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/controllers/home_controller.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/helpers/application_helper.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/javascript/application.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/javascript/controllers/application.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/javascript/controllers/hello_controller.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/javascript/controllers/index.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/jobs/application_job.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/mailers/application_mailer.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/models/application_record.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/models/user.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/_auth_layout.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/confirmations/new.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/mailer/email_changed.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/mailer/password_change.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/mailer/unlock_instructions.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/shared/_error_messages.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/devise/unlocks/new.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/home/index.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/layouts/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/layouts/application.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/shared/_flash_notice.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/shared/_head.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'app/views/shared/_navbar.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'bin/bundle', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'bin/bundle.cmd', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'bin/dev', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'bin/rails', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'bin/rake', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'bin/setup', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config.ru', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/application.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/boot.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/cable.yml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/database.yml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/environment.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/environments/development.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/environments/production.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/environments/test.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/initializers/assets.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/initializers/devise.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/initializers/friendly_id.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/initializers/inflections.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/initializers/permissions_policy.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/locales/devise.en.yml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/locales/en.yml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/puma.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/routes.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'config/storage.yml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'db/migrate/20230104203334_create_active_storage_tables.active_storage.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'db/migrate/20230104203357_create_action_text_tables.action_text.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'db/migrate/20230104203428_devise_create_users.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'db/migrate/20230104203445_create_friendly_id_slugs.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'db/seeds.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'lib/templates/erb/scaffold/_form.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'lib/templates/erb/scaffold/edit.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'lib/templates/erb/scaffold/index.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'lib/templates/erb/scaffold/new.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'lib/templates/erb/scaffold/show.html.erb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'package.json', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'public/404.html', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'public/422.html', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'public/500.html', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'public/robots.txt', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'tailwind.config.js', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'test/application_system_test_case.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'test/fixtures/action_text/rich_texts.yml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'test/fixtures/users.yml', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'test/models/user_test.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
warning: in the working copy of 'test/test_helper.rb', LF will be replaced by CRLF the next time Git touches it
  

Kickoff app successfully created! 

Switch to your app by running:
$ cd tweeter

Then run:
$ ./bin/dev
```

Above code I remove some usual parts because in here i can only past 30000 word/
then I ran .bin/dev but got error and it says,

```
$ ./bin/dev
23:36:15 web.1  | started with pid 2372
23:36:15 js.1   | started with pid 9768
23:36:15 css.1  | started with pid 19132
23:36:15 web.1  | 'unset' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
23:36:15 web.1  | operable program or batch file.
23:36:15 web.1  | exited with code 1
23:36:15 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:201:in `kill': Invalid argument (Errno::EINVAL)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:201:in `kill_children'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:473:in `terminate_gracefully'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:439:in `wait_for_shutdown_or_child_termination'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/engine.rb:60:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/cli.rb:42:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/lib/foreman/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/foreman-0.87.2/bin/foreman:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/foreman:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/foreman:32:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone please tell me what should I do thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `esbuild` is failing:

```
$ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets
X [ERROR] Could not resolve "app/javascript/*.*"

  It looks like you are trying to use glob syntax (i.e. "*") with esbuild. This syntax is typically handled by your shell, and isn't handled by esbuild itself. You must expand glob syntax first before passing your paths to esbuild.

1 error
node:child_process:910
    throw err;
    ^
```